# why won't my python if else statement input HTML?

Tags: python

I am trying to make it so when the user types Y it creates an HTML file in an email. But every single time it get's to that part in the code it won't run the if else statement or the HTML file.

```
sendLetter = "let's send a letter to your boss and tell him how much you like your job y or n"
letterToBoss = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>


<h1>dear Boss/h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
"""

if enjoyJob == "n" or "N":
  print("that's so sad ".join(name))
  input("why do you hate " + job + "?")
if enjoyJob == 'y' or 'Y':
    print("that is awesome").join(name)
    input(sendLetter)
    if sendLetter() == 'y' or 'Y':
      f = open("letter_to_Boss.html", "x")
    f.write(letterToBoss)
    f.read("letter_to_Boss.html")
    f.close()
    if sendLetter() == 'n' or 'N':
        print("awe shucks")
```

Comment: Try `if sendLetter ...`, not `if sendLetter() ...`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy that didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. You are missing your input code.

```
enjoyJob = str(input("Do you enjoy your job?"))
```

### 2. String comparisons cannot be done with the `or` statement.

```py
if enjoyJob == "n" or "N": # Does not work.
if enjoyJob in ("n", "N"): # Does work.
```

Python evaluates each side of the `or` statement as its own. Your code is the equivalent of doing:

```py
bool1 = bool(enjoyJob == "n") # Depends on enjoyJob.
bool2 = bool("N") # Is always true, since its not an empty string. 

if bool1 or bool2:
    ....
```

### 3. `name` and `job` is not defined, [`.join()`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join) does not do what you think it does.

```py
print("that's so sad ".join(name))
input("why do you hate " + job + "?")
```

```
>>> a = "hey"
>>> a.join("lol")
'lheyoheyl'
```

### 4. `input(sendLetter)` does not create new variable `sendLetter`.

You must assign a variable to the input, and the parameter for the `input` function is what is printed to the user. Correct usage is:

```
user_input = input("Please type in some input: ")
```

### 5. You must state what your logic must do if the user doesn't specify `y`.

Notice:

```
if sendLetter() == 'y' or 'Y':
  f = open("letter_to_Boss.html", "x")
f.write(letterToBoss)
f.read("letter_to_Boss.html")
f.close()
```

If the user types `n`, the program will crash since the file `f` was never initialized.

### 6. You do not (and can not) read from the opened file.

```
f = open("letter_to_Boss.html", "x")
f.write(letterToBoss)
f.read("letter_to_Boss.html") # This will return an error. 
f.close()
```

`f.read()` will not allow you to read the file (you must open the file with the intention of reading it), and for your purposes, it has no use.

---

### Final Code

With the corrections above, you get a code that looks more like so:

```py
letterToBoss = """<html>"""

name = str(input("What is your name?"))
job = str(input("What is your job?"))
enjoyJob = str(input("Do you enjoy your job?"))

if enjoyJob in ("n", "N"):
    print(f"that's so sad {name}")
    input(f"why do you hate {job}?")
elif enjoyJob in ("y", "Y"):
    print(f"that is awesome {name}")

    sendLetter = input("Would you like to send an email to your boss?")
    if sendLetter == ("y", "Y"):
        f = open("letter_to_Boss.html", "x")
        f.write(letterToBoss)
        f.close()
    elif sendLetter == ("n", "N"):
        print("awe shucks")
```

Comment: the name variable was added earlier

Comment: What do you mean? What # are you referring to?

Comment: Code is executed sequentially, which means if you do `print(name)` in one line, and then five lines later do `name = "Felipe"`, your program will crash saying it does not know what the variable `name` is on the `print(name)` line.

Comment: so python is different then javascript where in javascript I can store variables and in python, I can't

Comment: You can store variables in Python just the same way you can in Javascript, but with any programming language, you must do so sequentially for your machine to understand it. A computer is a "logic machine" for a lack of better words, and therefore you must give input to it in a way it can understand. In JS you do `var name = "Felipe"` before accessing it, in Python you have to do `name = "Felipe"` before accessing it as well. Compilers/interpreters aren't magical things that can guess what you mean -- you have to purposefully define variables before you access them. :)

Comment: I should also add that this wouldn't be the case if you were defining a function that takes in the parameter `name` and any other you are missing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201770/discussion-between-zachary-blumstein-and-felipe-faria).

Answer (score 0):

1. `input()` returns a value. You don't call it then call the variable. So, this would be correct:

```
if input(sendLetter) == 'y': # here comes the second problem
```

2. `or` checks if two *full expressions* are true. You can't use it like `a == b or c`. Or, exactly, you can use it, but if c is not None and not 0, it means True so the whole expression will be true. But instead, if you want to check for multiple values, you can use `in`:

```
if input(sendLetter) in ('y', 'Y'):
    # code here
```

Comment: what is the `in` doing?

Comment: @ZacharyBlumstein If you do `if a == "str1" or "str2"` you are essentially doing `if a == "str1" or True` since Python evaluates each side of the `or` statement alone, and a non-empty string is always evaluated to be `True`. The `in` variable is literally asking Python `is var [in]side the list ('y', 'Y')`.

Comment: It checks if the value is in a collection. But check @FelipeFaria's answer, he described the problems better than me.